# IN XMPP getting exception not-authorized(401), while submitting the form

Tags: java, android, xmpp

I am able to add group, but it showing 'The room is locked from entry until configuration is confirmed'. I researched but did't find any satisfactory answer. Below is the code how it getting XMPP connection and submitting the form. And while sending the form it throwing ' Not authorized exception'.

```
xmppConnection = connectionThread.getXMPPConnection();
    if (xmppConnection == null) {
        Application.getInstance().onError(R.string.NOT_CONNECTED);
        return;
    }
    final MultiUserChat multiUserChat;
    try {

        multiUserChat = new MultiUserChat(xmppConnection, room);
    //  setConfig(multiUserChat);

    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Application.getInstance().onError(R.string.NOT_CONNECTED);
        return;
    }
```

//Code for submitting form.

```
private void setConfig(MultiUserChat multiUserChat) {

    try {
        Form form = multiUserChat.getConfigurationForm();
        Form submitForm = form.createAnswerForm();
        for (Iterator<FormField> fields = submitForm.getFields(); fields
                .hasNext();) {
            FormField field = (FormField) fields.next();
            if (!FormField.TYPE_HIDDEN.equals(field.getType())
                    && field.getVariable() != null) {
                submitForm.setDefaultAnswer(field.getVariable());
            }
        }
        submitForm.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_publicroom", true);
        submitForm.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_persistentroom", true);
        multiUserChat.sendConfigurationForm(submitForm);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Problem has been solved now, I was calling the setConfig() method from wrong place. It should be call after joining the group.  multiUserChat.join(nickname, password);
// set default config for the room
     setDefaultConfig(multiUserChat);

Comment: You can answer your own question and accept it. :)

Answer (score 1):

To get this Question answered, I just adapt your comment.

You are calling `setConfig()` to early. It should be called after joining the group.